# How to make Searching functionality for whole database in django/DRF using single API?

Tags: python, django, search, django-rest-framework

How to make Search in whole database using django/DRF single API?

For example we can do this for single model search using django/DRF API:-

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['category', 'in_stock']
```

You can see the whole example in this:-
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Thank you in ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different packages out there for connecting django-filters to django-rest. Each have their own strengths and weaknesses. However I prefer this simple solution:

**views.py**

```py
def BaseAPIView(...):

    ''' base view for other views to inherit '''

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = self.queryset

        # get filter request from client:
        filter_string = self.request.query_params.get('filter')

        # apply filters if they are passed in:
        if filters: 
            filter_dictionary = json.loads(filter_string)
            queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_dictionary)

        return queryset
```

The request url will now look like, for example: `my_website.com/api/products?filters={"name":"book"}`

Or more precisely: `my_website.com/api/products?filters=%7B%22name%22:%22book%22%7D`

Which can be built like:

**script.js**

```js
// using ajax as an example:
var filter = JSON.stringify({
  "name" : "book"
});

$.ajax({
   "url" : "my_website.com/api/products?filter=" + filters,
   "type" : "GET",
   ...
});
```

**Some advantages:**

- no need to specify which fields can be filtered on each view class
- write it once, use it everywhere
- front end filtering looks exactly like django filtering
- can do the same with `exclude`

**Some disadvantages:**

- potential security risks if you want some fields to be non-filterable
- less intuitive front-end code to query a table

Overall, this approach has been far more useful for me than any packages out there.